# Why do I get this Babel JSON config error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

So I'm creating this react website, but not JSX but TSX. I'm using webpack and Babel. Need help with this error I get when running `webpack-dev-server`

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
...
Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character '�' at 1:1
```

Here's my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.scss']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        publicPath: '/',
        contentBase: './public',
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            ...
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './components/App/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I've searched everywhere, but nothing satisfactory. Hope I can get more inputs in this forum.

Comment: can you post your `index.tsx` file? looks like its probably trying to import a non-UTF character maybe from a PNG or SVG?

Comment: @Derek see edit

Comment: Is this really the whole error message?

Comment: @madflow nope but stack won't allow me to put more code than non-code lol. Practically the rest is by` json5\lib\parse`.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error like this and it was a typo in my tsconfig.json file.